# papaja and text references knitting to word

Tags: r, ms-word, knitr, papaja

I am trying to create text references for tables and figures. However, I do get it to work following the examples in the documentation. There is neither a text reference nor a table caption using either approach. Here is some example script.

````
    # Results

    See Table \@ref(tab:ResultsANOVAI) or Table \@ref(tab:ResultsANOVAII) for ANOVA results. They show  that ...

    (ref:ResultsANOVAI) Results ANOVA I

    ```{r ANOVAI, warning=FALSE, tab.cap='(ref:ResultsANOVAI)'}
    library(afex)
    daten <- data.frame(vp = rep(1:30, each = 6),
                        cond1 = rep(1:3, each = 2),
                        cond2 = rep(1:2),
                        rt = rnorm(180, 600, 100))

    aov.res <- aov_ez("vp", "rt", daten, within = c("cond1", "cond2"))

    apa_anova <- apa_print.afex_aov(aov.res)
    apa_table(apa_anova$table)
    ```

    A little bit of text after the table.

    (ref:ResultsANOVAI) Results ANOVA II

    ```{r ANOVAII, warning=FALSE}
    apa_anova <- apa_print.afex_aov(aov.res)
    apa_table(apa_anova$table,
              caption = "(ref:ResultsANOVAII)")
    ```
````

Hints are heartly welcome.

Jens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the following code should work:

````
    # Results

    See Table \@ref(tab:ANOVAI) or Table \@ref(tab:ANOVAII) for ANOVA results. They     show  that ...

    (ref:ResultsANOVAI) Results ANOVA I

    ```{r ANOVAI, warning=FALSE}
    library(afex)
    daten <- data.frame(vp = rep(1:30, each = 6),
                    cond1 = rep(1:3, each = 2),
                    cond2 = rep(1:2),
                    rt = rnorm(180, 600, 100))

    aov.res <- aov_ez("vp", "rt", daten, within = c("cond1", "cond2"))

    apa_anova <- apa_print.afex_aov(aov.res)
    apa_table(apa_anova$table, caption = "(ref:ResultsANOVAI)")
    ```

    A little bit of text after the table.

    (ref:ResultsANOVAII) Results ANOVA II

    ```{r ANOVAII, warning=FALSE}
    apa_anova <- apa_print.afex_aov(aov.res)
    apa_table(apa_anova$table,
          caption = "(ref:ResultsANOVAII)")
    ```
````

So why did your code not work?

- When you want to add a caption to a table via text references, add something like `caption = "(ref:caption-name)"` to your call to `apa_table()` (the chunk option `tab.cap` does not work)
- When you are using cross references (i.e., "see Table 1 and 2"), use `\@ref(tab:chunk-name)` -- your chunk names are `ANOVAI` and `ANOVAII` in your example, so it has to be `\@ref(tab:ANOVAI)` and `\@ref(tab:ANOVAII)`

Hope this helps!

For further reading, the relevant parts of the `papaja` manual are here:

- [Table captions](https://crsh.github.io/papaja_man/reporting.html#table-captions)
- [Cross references](https://crsh.github.io/papaja_man/writing.html#cross-referencing)

Comment: Thanks a lot: I found my error. I was referring to the caption reference and not the chunk-name.